# Resizing a matrix to fit into the page width

Tags: amsmath

I am trying to resize a matrix so that it fits into the page width. I read some solutions, but I am already using other matrices in my document, I am trying to find a solution that would change only one matrix environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}


\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-\lambda u_t}{u^2}+uu_x-(-u_xu_{xx}-uu_{xxx}-2u_xu_{xx}) & i (+uu_{xx}+u_x^2-4 \lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x+2\lambda)-(i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}+2\lambda u_x)) \\


i(-uu_{xx}-u_x^2+4\lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x-2 \lambda)+i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}-2\lambda u_x) & \dfrac{\lambda u_t}{u^2}-uu_x-(u_x u_{xx}+uu_{xxx}+2u_x u_{xx})\\
\end{bmatrix}

\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The posted code produces the error  `! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106587/scale-an-equation-to-fit-exact-page-width

Comment: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6488

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

- in any equation code had not to be empty lines
- for shrinking your equation to text width I suggest to use `\medmath` from the `nccmath` package (which reduce equation size for about 1/4)
- split long math term into two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\medmath{
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{multlined}
-\mfrac{\lambda u_t}{u^2}+uu_x  \\
-(-u_xu_{xx}-uu_{xxx}-2u_xu_{xx}) 
\end{multlined} &   \begin{multlined}
                    i(+uu_{xx}+u_x^2-4 \lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x+2\lambda)  \\ 
                    - i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}+2\lambda u_x)
                    \end{multlined}     \\[7ex]
\begin{multlined}
i(-uu_{xx}-u_x^2+4\lambda^2)    \\
+2i\lambda (u_x-2 \lambda)+i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}-2\lambda u_x)
\end{multlined} &   \begin{multlined}
                    \mfrac{\lambda u_t}{u^2} - uu_x \\
                    -(u_x u_{xx}+uu_{xxx}+2u_x u_{xx})
                    \end{multlined}
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Shrinking  the text should only be as a last resort (and even then avoid doing it)

I would use a layout such as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}% don't use align if no alignment
\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
a_{11}&=\frac{-\lambda u_t}{u^2}+uu_x-(-u_xu_{xx}-uu_{xxx}-2u_xu_{xx})\\
a_{12}&=i (+uu_{xx}+u_x^2-4 \lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x+2\lambda)-(i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}+2\lambda u_x)) \\
a_{21}&=i(-uu_{xx}-u_x^2+4\lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x-2 \lambda)+i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}-2\lambda u_x) \\
a_{22}&=\frac{\lambda u_t}{u^2}-uu_x-(u_x u_{xx}+uu_{xxx}+2u_x u_{xx})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you try to fix the equation within the text width, then try with `adjustbox.sty`, but the resolution may affects, here is the `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=[r][0.5\textwidth][b]{0.25\textwidth},scale={0.6}}{
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{-\lambda u_t}{u^2}+uu_x-(-u_xu_{xx}-uu_{xxx}-2u_xu_{xx}) & i (+uu_{xx}+u_x^2-4 \lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x+2\lambda)-(i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}+2\lambda u_x)) \\
i(-uu_{xx}-u_x^2+4\lambda^2)+2i\lambda (u_x-2 \lambda)+i(u^2_x+uu_{xx}-2\lambda u_x) & \dfrac{\lambda u_t}{u^2}-uu_x-(u_x u_{xx}+uu_{xxx}+2u_x u_{xx})\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\adjustbox` method virtually guarantees an impossibly small fontsize and hence  illegibility of the material in the matrix. You should really mention this in your answer, just to alert potential future readers of your answer to be on their guard.

Comment: you should in particular say what effective font size this produces for the subscript t in the fraction of the first entry,,,,,